# How to determine the number of unique intersections for multiple oscillating curves on the x-axis?

Tags: analytic-geometry, harmonic-functions

Suppose one has multiple $\sin/\cos$ wave curves with different periodicity.  The question is to determine the unique count of intersections of the combined curves with the $x$-axis.  For example, if we have two curves $y=\sin(\pi x)$ and $y=\sin(\pi x/3)$ it is clear that for the first curve, whenever $x$ is divisible by $2$ the first function yields $0$ and so the wave intersects the $x$-axis at all $x$ where $x$ is even. For the second curve, it will intersect the $x$-axis whenever $x$ is a multiple of $3$. In fact, one can say that for the function $y=\sin(\pi x/n)$ the curve will intersect the $x$-axis with a periodicity $n$.

So, if there are two curves, say our example above, each graphed on the same $x/y$-axis, the number of combined unique intersections with the $x$-axis is actually not the sum of the two curves since there will be combined intersections for numbers that are multiples of $6$.
The question then is how to construct a counting function for the number of unique intersections that n curves will have on the $x$-axis? The compound function

$$C(x)= \sin(\pi x/a)\sin(\pi x/b)\sin(\pi x/c)\cdots\sin(\pi x/n)$$

creates a curve that intersects the x-axis exactly at the unique points of each individual curve.  The reason that this works is that an $x$-axis intersection point for any of the individual curves gives $0$ and thus determines the value of $C(x)$ regardless of the values of the other elements of the function.

One can create a function $A(x)$ such that it is defined to be $1$ whenever $C(x)=0$, and $0$ otherwise.  Then one can sum $C(x)$ for each integer value of $x$ over its range, 1 to R. This accomplishes the task, but it is awkward.  It would be preferable to create a function, $C(x)$, such that it takes on the value of 1 at each x-axis intersection point.

Using cos, in theory, would provide an elegant solution to this problem, but unfortunately, it doesn’t work.  If, for example, $x=2$, $|\cos(\pi x/2)| = 1$, but $|\cos(\pi x/3)| = 0.5$.  Thus, the compound equation of the 2, even using absolute values, is 0.5. This becomes more difficult as one superimposes more curves, e.g.$|\cos(\pi x/5)| = 0.8$ and $|\cos(\pi x/7)| = 0.623$.  This means that it doesn’t yield a count of the intersections. Unless there is a different radian expression that I am missing, cos cannot be made to work for this problem.

Another possible solution would be to use combinations to determine the count, basically counting the intersections as the sum of $1$/periodicities less the intersection points, but this also becomes cumbersome quickly as the number of curves increases.

While this count issue seems to be a problem in analytic geometry, I haven’t thought of or found an answer.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

A possible implementation for $A(x)$ would be:

\begin{equation}
 A(x) =
  \begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if} \hspace{3mm} (x\equiv 0 \mod a) \land (x\equiv 0 \mod b) \land \ldots \land (x\equiv 0 \mod n) \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
as $C(x) = 0$ only when $x$ is a multiple of the denominator ($a, b, ...$).

If you have cosines as a function, I would suggest making a separate $C(x)$ for cosines and use the same idea as before.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It's a bit more efficient than what I created:   Define the function:

A(x)=∏_(i=1)^n▒sin((x*π)/p_i ) 

This function returns 0 when x is a multiple of some prime, pi but is otherwise nonzero.

Thus, we can define the inversion function:

I(x)={█(1 if A(x)=0@0 otherwise)┤

This means that we can count all the excluded integers from 1 to R-1 that are excluded as candidates as factors of R:

C(R,P)=∑_(x=1)^(R-1)▒I(x) 

This means that the fraction of integers that cannot be factors of R is:

F(R,P)=(C(R,P))/R